# Prove, that the following rules for homomorphisms are true or false.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, computer-science, formal-languages, group-homomorphism

> Let $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, $L$ and $R$ be languages over $\Sigma$ and $h:\Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ be a homomorphism. Prove or disprove the following statements:
>
> 1. $h^{-1}(L\cup R)=h^{-1}(L)\cup h^{-1}(R)$
> 2. $L=h^{-1}(h(L))$

---

$\begin{align}
h^{-1}(L\cup R)&=\{x\in\Sigma^*\mid h(x) \in L\cup R\}\\
&=\{x\in\Sigma^*\mid h(x)\in L \lor h(x)\in R\}\\
&=\{x\in\Sigma^* \mid h(x)\in L\}\cup \{x\in\Sigma^*\mid h(x)\in R\}\\
&=h^{-1}(L)\cup h^{-1}(R)
\end{align}$

---

$L=h^{-1}(h(L))$

No, let $L=\{aab,ba,aa,b\}$ and $h(a)=\lambda$, $h(b)=b$, $\left((h(\lambda)=\lambda\right)$. It follows, that $h(L)=\{b,b,\lambda,b\}$ and $h^{-1}(h(L))=\{b,b,\lambda,b\}$, but $L\neq h^{-1}(h(L))$. The statement is not true.

Are both proofs correct? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution for (1) is correct.

Your solution for (2) is not correct. With your choice of $h$ and $L$, one has $h(L) = \{b, 1\}$ (where $1$ is the empty word, a better notation when you use monoid homomorphisms, since the empty word is the identity of the monoid $\Sigma^*$). Then $h^{-1}(h(L)) = a^*ba^* + a^* \not = L$.

A much simpler example is to take $h(a) = h(b) = 1$ and $L = \{1\}$. Then $h(L) = \{1\}$ and $h^{-1}(h(L)) = \Sigma^*$.